# Double same key keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut, key-bindings

Is there a way to use the same key for a shortcut?  For example, on Mac, IntelliJ uses `shift shift` (double tap the shift key) for searches.  I would like to mimic that function in VSCode, but it doesn't appear to accept that as a valid shortcut.  I can save it, but nothing happens when I try to use it.

Comment: I think in vscode the `shift` key can only be used as a `modifier` and not alone. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys

Comment: I tried binding `shift shift` to some action but it didn't work, I guess it is not yet supported.

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364400/how-can-i-make-a-keybinding-composed-of-only-modifiers-in-vscode/66014481#66014481 as well as the other duplicate question noted above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible, with VSCode 1.54 (Feb. 2021)

> ### [Modifier only keybindings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b3eaecb3787c7bafe192303358a6ca2e24be429f/release-notes/v1_54.md#modifier-only-keybindings)
>
> It is now possible to define keybindings for **duplicate modifiers**:
> e.g. <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> / <kbd>meta</kbd> <kbd>meta</kbd> / <kbd>win</kbd> <kbd>win</kbd>.
> These keybindings can be entered manually in keybindings.json. e.g.:
>
> ```
> { "key": "shift shift", "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen" }
> ```

Comment: Where can I find `{keybindings.json` on windows 11?

Comment: @LikiCrus VSCode can open it for you as [explained here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization). You will see its path then. For me: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\keybindings.json`.