# How can I make a keybinding composed of only modifiers in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make a keybinding composed of only modifiers? Example:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt",
  "command": "cursorLeft",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can.  As you have probably seen, the keybinding `key` consists of a modifier plus some key (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys).  And you want to have no accepted keys -you could use something like `alt+backspace` though.  Also there are a lot of default keybindings that start with `shift+alt` so vscode is always going to wait for the final `key`.  Maybe if you disabled all of those it would work but I still doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Some ability to do this appears it is in the Insiders' Build v1.54, see 
[Feature: Shift Shift, Ctrl Ctrl, Alt Alt Keybinds (Double press modifier keybind support)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/115190)
 .

However, it is limited to:

```
Shift Shift
Ctrl Ctrl
Alt Alt
Meta Meta
Win Win
```

so `"key": "shift alt"` does not work.

So you could do

```
{
  "key": "shift shift",
  "command": "cursorLeft",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

**NOTE** : there is no `+` between the modifier keys, so

```
  "key": "shift+shift",
```

does not currently work - tested.